# linq with expression in the select field

Tags: c#, linq

I need to perform some complex calculations for the "CalculatedField" but I am getting an error "Cannot assign lambda expression to anonymous type property". How can I solve this calculation in an elegant way?

```
var query =
    from person in people
    join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner
    select new
    {
        OwnerName = person.FirstName,
        PetName = pet.Name,
        CalculatedField = () => { return "blah-blah") 
    };
```

Comment: Do you intend `CalculatedField` to be a method that is executed later, outside the query, or the property should be a string (or other simple type) calculated during the query?

Comment: Assuming `CalculatedField` should just be the string, you can immediately invoke it with `CalculatedField = () => { return "blah-blah" }()`

Comment: Instead of an anonymous type, can you define a class which has this method and select a new instance of that class?

Answer (score 1):

You can just determine the calculated result before assigning the value to avoid setting the lamda expression to an anonymous type

```
var query =
from person in people
join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner
let calculatedResult = ComplexCalculation() 
select new
{
    OwnerName = person.FirstName,
    PetName = pet.Name,
    CalculatedField = calculatedResult
};

private string ComplexCalculation()
{
    return "blah-blah";
}
```

Comment: no need for the `let`, though, unless it is needed in multiple places in the projection - you can just do `select new { ..., CalculatedField = ComplexCalculation() }`

Answer (score 1):

With your syntax it thinks that you are trying to assign the Lambada to the CalcualtedField variable. You can't just start the Lambada anywhere you want. The compiler has no context for what kind of value you are trying to assign to the anonymous class's variable so it assumes that you are trying to assign the lambada.

Given the information you gave us, I recommend breaking it out into a separate method. For Example:

```
    var query =
from person in people
join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner
select new
{
    OwnerName = person.FirstName,
    PetName = pet.Name,
    CalculatedField = DoCalculation()
};
```

Then you have another method "DoCalculation" that takes in the parameters it needs and performs the calculation and returns your value.

```
public string DoCalculation()
{
    return "blah-blah";
}
```

Adding another item for completeness. You could also invoke the lambada immediately by following it up with (). However, I would only recommend this if it is a very simple statement. If it has any complexity a secondary method is usually the more readable way to go.